# rspec-puppet testing fails due to unavailable gems

Tags: puppet, rspec-puppet

I'm trying to write tests for rspec-puppet testing.

The module has the following tree:

```
 |-- manifests
    |   `-- test_file.pp
    |-- Rakefile
    `-- spec
        |-- classes
        |-- defines
        |   `-- test_file_spec.rb
        |-- fixtures
        |   |-- manifests
        |   |   `-- site.pp
        |   `-- modules
        |       `-- test
        |           |-- files -> ../../../../files
        |           |-- lib -> ../../../../lib
        |           |-- manifests -> ../../../../manifests
        |           `-- templates -> ../../../../templates
        |-- functions
        |-- hosts
        `-- spec_helper.rb
```

I am getting the below error when I run "rake rspec"

```
(in /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/modules/offshore/test)
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- rspec/core/rake_task
/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/modules/offshore/test/Rakefile:2
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

When I run "rake spec --trace" it gives the following:

```
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- rspec/core/rake_task
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/modules/offshore/test/Rakefile:2
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2382:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2382:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2016:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2067:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2015:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1999:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2067:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1997:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
```

Can some one help me with setting it up?

Comment: You might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31128450/2180697

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `Gemfile` with the following content in the root of your module:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

group :test do
  gem 'rake'
  gem 'puppet', ENV['PUPPET_VERSION'] || '~> 3.4.0'
  gem 'puppet-lint'
  gem 'rspec-puppet', :git => 'https://github.com/rodjek/rspec-puppet.git'
  gem 'puppet-syntax'
  gem 'puppetlabs_spec_helper'
  gem 'simplecov'
  gem 'metadata-json-lint'
end
```

Then run `bundle install`

Then run `bundle exec rake spec`

There's also a useful tool `puppet-retrospec` that will automatically add specs to an existing module: https://github.com/logicminds/puppet-retrospec, this might help you.