# Why do I get puppet-rspec 'class does not exist' when it does?

Tags: rspec, puppet, rspec-puppet

I setup a new puppet `demo` module with the following `Gemfile` and it worked as expected when I ran a simple puppet-rspec test.

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


if puppetversion = ENV['PUPPET_GEM_VERSION']
  gem 'puppet', puppetversion, :require => false
else
  gem 'puppet', '3.7.5' 
end


gem 'metadata-json-lint'
gem 'puppetlabs_spec_helper', '>= 0.1.0'
gem 'puppet-lint', '>= 1.0.0'
gem 'facter', '>= 1.7.0'
gem 'rspec-puppet-facts' 


# rspec must be v2 for ruby 1.8.7
if RUBY_VERSION >= '1.8.7' and RUBY_VERSION < '1.9'
  gem 'rspec', '~> 2.0'
end
```

However when I cloned an existing module (`silex`)  and updated the Gemfile to look like the above and I run:

```
bundle exec rake spec
```

**I get the following error:**

```
vagrant$ bundle exec rake spec
/usr/bin/ruby -S rspec spec/classes/init_spec.rb --color
F


Failures:


  1) silex with defaults for all parameters should contain Class[silex]
     Failure/Error: it { should contain_class('silex') }
     Puppet::Error:
       Could not find class silex for centos65-box-1 on node centos65-box-1
     # ./spec/classes/init_spec.rb:5


Finished in 0.31963 seconds
1 example, 1 failure


Failed examples:


rspec ./spec/classes/init_spec.rb:5 # silex with defaults for all parameters should contain Class[silex]
```

The class exists and I have already done a puppet run. Can someone assist me understanding why this would be the case?

**More information**

```
    # Tree
    .
    ├── files
    │   └── httpd.patch
    ├── Gemfile
    ├── Gemfile.lock
    ├── lib
    │   └── facter
    │       └── vendor_dir.rb
    ├── manifests
    │   ├── backup.pp
    │   ├── config.pp
    │   ├── init.pp
    │   ├── install.pp
    │   ├── params.pp
    │   └── service.pp
    ├── metadata.json
    ├── Rakefile
    ├── README.md
    ├── spec
    │   ├── classes
    │   │   └── init_spec.rb
    │   ├── fixtures
    │   │   ├── manifests
    │   │   │   └── site.pp
    │   │   └── modules
    │   └── spec_helper.rb
    ├── templates
    │   └── var
    │       └── config
    │           └── settings.json.erb
    └── tests
        └── init.pp




# spec_helper.rb
require 'puppetlabs_spec_helper/module_spec_helper'
require 'rspec-puppet-facts'
include RspecPuppetFacts



#init_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
describe 'silex' do

  context 'with defaults for all parameters' do
    it { should contain_class('silex') }
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you run 'tree' on the modules root, show the contents of the spec_helper and what the class spec looks like?

Comment: You will need the `silex` module in `spec/fixtures/modules` for `rspec-puppet` to be able to load it.

Comment: Testing a module always seems to be when the puppet autoloader becomes the most annoying, I wish there was a better way to handle this.

Comment: @FelixFrank: Looks like I found the source of the problem. I needed to run `rspec-puppet-init`  to ensure it creates the necessary symlinks to my manifests, templates. etc.

Comment: @aspiringCodeArtisan Please add that as an answer and accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out I was missing the `module` in the `fixtures` dir causing the `could not find class` error.

**Immediate Solution**

I had to run `rspec-puppet-init` which updates my `spec` dir including the `spec_helper.rb` file to the following:

```
    require 'rspec-puppet'

    fixture_path = File.expand_path(File.join(__FILE__, '..', 'fixtures'))

    RSpec.configure do |c|
      c.module_path = File.join(fixture_path, 'modules')
      c.manifest_dir = File.join(fixture_path, 'manifests')
      c.environmentpath = File.join(Dir.pwd, 'spec')
    end
```

---

**Detailed Solution**

Here are all the steps I took to get this to work. I would love to get some feed back on if this is the best approach:

#### 1. Add to `Gemfile` and run:

```
    #You may need to tweak the versions depending on what your environment is like.
    bundle install
```

**Gemfile**:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

if puppetversion = ENV['PUPPET_GEM_VERSION']
  gem 'puppet', puppetversion, :require => false
else
  gem 'puppet', '3.7.5'
end


gem 'metadata-json-lint'
gem 'puppetlabs_spec_helper', '>= 0.1.0'
gem 'puppet-lint', '>= 1.0.0'
gem 'facter', '>= 1.7.0'
gem 'rspec-puppet-facts'


# rspec must be v2 for ruby 1.8.7
if RUBY_VERSION >= '1.8.7' and RUBY_VERSION < '1.9'
  gem 'rspec', '~> 2.0'
end
```

#### 2. Initialize your `spec` dir. Run from module root dir.

```
bundle exec rspec-puppet-init
```

#### 3. I had to update the auto generated `Rakefile` to the following:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'puppetlabs_spec_helper/rake_tasks'
require 'puppet-lint/tasks/puppet-lint'
PuppetLint.configuration.send('disable_80chars')
PuppetLint.configuration.ignore_paths = ["spec/**/*.pp", "pkg/**/*.pp"]

desc "Validate manifests, templates, and ruby files"
task :validate do
  Dir['manifests/**/*.pp'].each do |manifest|
    sh "puppet parser validate --noop #{manifest}"
  end
  Dir['spec/**/*.rb','lib/**/*.rb'].each do |ruby_file|
    sh "ruby -c #{ruby_file}" unless ruby_file =~ /spec\/fixtures/
  end
  Dir['templates/**/*.erb'].each do |template|
    sh "erb -P -x -T '-' #{template} | ruby -c"
  end
end
```

#### 4. Run `bundle exec rake spec` from module root dir